# add elements to listView dynamically

Tags: android, listview

I have to list all the elements of a String Array in a two line listView.

The String Array is dynamically and can either change in size or in content. So when the size of the String Array is 5 for example 5 listView elements shall be shown.

Have you got any idea how to do that?

I have tried it with this, but this list only the first element:

```
 // wenn noch keine Standorte hinterlegt sind gibt es eine CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException
    try {
        datum_global = datenBankHelper.get_datum();
        int alle_eintraege_aller_datumsangaben = datum_global.length; // Alle Einträge von allen Datumsangaben (auch von gleichen)

        Log.d("size", "size " + alle_eintraege_aller_datumsangaben + "|" + datum_global[0]);        // z.B. 27, da 27 Einträge für alle Datumsangaben

        for(int i= 0; i < alle_eintraege_aller_datumsangaben; i++) {
            gespeicherte_routen = new String[][]{
                    {datum_global[i], "Anzahl Einträge: " + "Test"}
            };
        }

    } catch (CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException cs){

    }


    @SuppressWarnings("Convert2Diamond") ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list = null;

    // wenn noch keine Standorte hinterlegt sind gibt es eine NullPointerException
    try {
        list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        HashMap<String, String> item;
        for (String[] routen : gespeicherte_routen) {

            Log.d("schleife3", "schleife3 " + routen[0] + "|" + routen[1] + gespeicherte_routen.length);
            //noinspection Convert2Diamond
            item = new HashMap<String, String>();
            item.put("line1", routen[0]);
            item.put("line2", routen[1]);

            list.add(item);
        }

    }catch(NullPointerException np){

    }
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: can you explain it more clearly

Comment: It is the simple listview, nothing special. Use any listView tutorial, found in google in about 8 seconds

Answer (score 1):

a `ListView` needs an `Adapter` to show the data, and the `Adapter` needs a `List` (of strings in this case). if you change the values in the list you just need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `Adapter` and the `ListView` will update on its own

```
ListView mListView;
ArrayAdapter mAdapter;
List<String> mList;

//...

mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(context, R.layout.something, mList);
mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

// .. 

mList.add("bla bla");
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```